# Is there a interactive debugger for php like ruby's debugger?

Tags: php, ruby, debugging, interactive

I watched the [Creating a weblog in 15 minutes with Rails 2](http://rubyonrails.org/screencasts) and after 9 minutes in the video he shows ruby's interactive debugger, which allows you to call functions/methods from within a running script.

This goes way beyond breakpoints and looks very useful.

Is there something for PHP that gives similar functionality?

Comment: You mean you don't want to use the time honoured echo ... method?  Heresy!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although [Milen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/575058/4463672) is the only correct one circa 2009, and Xdebug is still a useful tool, using it requires you to recompile your PHP or to edit your `php.ini` runtime configuration to load it as a shared object. It also means using a specific client application that supports its network protocol, such as an IDE like PhpStorm.

An alternative is [`phpdbg`](http://phpdbg.com/), which is an interactive debugger that [ships with PHP core versions 5.6 and later](https://secure.php.net/manual/debugger-about.php) and can debug PHP scripts written to conform to PHP 5.4 or later.

Using it is simple:

```
phpdbg php_script_i_want_to_debug.php
```

Once in the debugger, type `help` to access the help menu.

If you don't already have `phpdbg` on your system, it may be because your PHP was configured without the `--enable-phpdbg` option. You can either:

1. Recompile your PHP, being sure to add `--enable-phpdbg` when you run `./configure` (this will simply also build the `phpdbg` binary), or
2. download the `phpdbg` source independently and compile it against your installed PHP (assuming you have the PHP source available). Instructions for doing that, while sparse, are [here](http://phpdbg.com/docs).

Answer (score 9):

Install [xdebug](http://www.xdebug.org/) and then use one of the debug clients mentioned [here](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/remote).